# Make a global dict object in python which can access and edit from any py files

Tags: python

I want keep some global data which can access and edit from any python files. I tried with python classes but it is not working across the files the code is given below.(Note :I am not interested to do any file operations)

```
class Settings(object):
    """docstring for Settings"""
    device = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Settings.device is None:
            Settings.device = DeviceSettings()



class DeviceSettings(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mode = None
        self.ops = []
        self.phyops = None

Settings()
Settings.device
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not a fan of this but if you really need it just create a global dict in a module and then import it:

```
#a.py

MY_GLOBAL_DICT = {}

#b.py

from a import MY_GLOBAL_DICT
MY_GLOBAL_DICT["hey"] = 10
```

Here you have a [working example](https://repl.it/I8HC/1)

Comment: Are you sure the updated value will be available in a.py after assignment ?

Comment: it should be available whithin the execution. just test it @Arun

Comment: In Python, module symbols are only loaded once per program run. A second import simply loads the cached module data for you, so this definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are mutable by default. You don't need to write a class for it.

```
# common.py
common_data = {
}

# file1.py
from common import common_data
common_data['key'] = 'value'
```

Now the important question, you need to ask is, is it advisable to use a global variable for mutation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by making the class `Settings` a `Singleton`
Note that in order to access device you need to do `self.device` instead of `Settings.device`

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance():
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance

class DeviceSettings(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mode = None
        self.ops = []
        self.phyops = None

@singleton
class Settings(object):
    """docstring for Settings"""
    device = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.device is None:
            self.device = DeviceSettings()




x = Settings()
print x.device

# In an another file y.device will return the last device value.
x.device = "Another device"
y = Settings()
print y.device
```